# Where is the ASP.Net Configuration Page?

Tags: .net, asp.net

In VS 2010, I create an ASP.NET Web Application with .Net Framework 4.  In all the tutorials I come across, there is a Web Site Administration Tool that is a web site that allows you to configure authorization and roles.  On the site that I have, I see no such link. What gives?

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2010, under the `Project` menu, select `ASP.NET Configuration`.

Comment: This is it.  Thanks.  I'm going through a tutorial on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I think you are referring to.

At the top of solution explorer is a icon that gets you to ASP.NET Configuration

[image]

Then that should launch your browser and take you to something like this.

[image]